# Setting Report Footer on the last page while saving as PDF

Tags: .net, rdlc

Me with C#.net and using report viewer control I am populating reports in my Report.rdlc, How can I show page number in my report on a given place and I had added footer in Report.rdlc, how can I show footer only at the ending page ie, if there are 3 pages how can I show the footer only in the 3rd page.
When i am exporting the report as PDF the footer is visible on all the pages. Please Help !

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following expression for the `Hidden` property of the items that you wish to hide.

```
=Iif(Globals!TotalPages = Globals!PageNumber, False, True)
```

Comment: What if two or more text boxes to hide? In this scenario place all text boxes inside a rectangle control and apply this visibility condition to the rectangle instead each text boxes. check [this](https://dileepakb.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/how-to-print-page-footer-at-bottom-and-on-last-page-of-a-rdlc-report-in-microsoft-dynamics-nav-2013-r2/) hope helps.